# CsvHelper fluent class mapping ConstructUsing() ignored in referenced maps?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, .net-4.5, csvhelper

I was wondering if I am doing this right, but I am using [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) and have the following fluent class maps defined:

```
        internal class WasteEstimationGenericDayCsvMap : CsvClassMap<WasteEstimationGenericDay>
        {
            public WasteEstimationGenericDayCsvMap(WasteEstimationGenericDay dayModel)
            {
                var qualityModel = dayModel.Quality;
                ConstructUsing(() => new WasteEstimationGenericDay(dayModel.ModelUnitContext));
                Map(m => m.InflowVolume).Name(dayModel.GetPropertyDisplayName(() => dayModel.InflowVolume));
                References<WasteStreamQualityCsvMap>(m => m.Quality, qualityModel);
            }
        }

        internal class WasteStreamQualityCsvMap : CsvClassMap<WasteStreamQuality>
        {
            public WasteStreamQualityCsvMap(WasteStreamQuality qualityModel)
            {
                ConstructUsing(() => new WasteStreamQuality(qualityModel.ModelUnitContext));
                Map(m => m.TotalNitrogen).Name(qualityModel.GetPropertyDisplayName(() => qualityModel.TotalNitrogen));
                Map(m => m.TotalPhosphorus).Name(qualityModel.GetPropertyDisplayName(() => qualityModel.TotalPhosphorus));
                Map(m => m.TotalDissolvedSalts).Name(qualityModel.GetPropertyDisplayName(() => qualityModel.TotalDissolvedSalts));
                Map(m => m.VolatileSolids).Name(qualityModel.GetPropertyDisplayName(() => qualityModel.VolatileSolids));
                Map(m => m.TotalSolids).Name(qualityModel.GetPropertyDisplayName(() => qualityModel.TotalSolids));
                Map(m => m.ElectricalConductivity).Name(qualityModel.GetPropertyDisplayName(() => qualityModel.ElectricalConductivity));
            }
        }
```

These class maps are designed to be able to map dynamic column names in no particular order to my type `WasteEstimationGenericDay`, however the problem is before mapping values to the type I need to specify the units those values are in, this is why `ConstructUsing()` is specified in each class map to set the units during the construction of the type for mapping.

However for the referenced class map for the type `WasteStreamQuality` on the property `WasteEstimationGenericDay.Quality, the`ConstructUsing()` statement is never called and the units are not specified. Does anyone know if I am doing something wrong in my mapping configuration? or is this a bug/limitation in [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper)?

I have also tried registering both class maps separately on the configuration like so:

```
      csvReaderConfig.RegisterClassMap(new WasteEstimationGenericDayCsvMap(dayModel));
      csvReaderConfig.RegisterClassMap(new WasteStreamQualityCsvMap(dayModel.Quality));
```

But it does not appear to have any affect unless it is the type that was specified when calling `CsvReader.GetRecords<T>()`.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After also posting this question as an [issue](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/477) I got the following response:

> Taking a quick look at the source (as I don't have a computer to test it on at the moment), it looks like that isn't implemented, but should be a pretty quick thing to do.